trace in group algebras
Let $KG$ be the group algebra of $G$ over $K$. For $a \in KG$, we usually define $tr(a)$ as the trace of left multiplication $a: x \mapsto ax$ for $x \in KG$. In Lam's book on noncommutative rings, I saw $tr(a)=a_{1_G}$ when each element of $KG$ has the form $a=\sum_ga_gg$. Is there any relation between these two definitions?

Lam’s trace is 1/|G| the trace defined by left multiplication

Page 82 of A first course on noncommutative rings before the proof of Lemma 6.5, Lam says "For any element $a = \sum a_gg$ in the complex group algebra $\mathbb{C}G$, we define the trace of a to be $tr(a) = a_1\in \mathbb{C}$."
